# Can i give dangerous permissions from settings?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

so far I've run the situation on a rooted device and an emulator. I can't find clear information on whether i can run my application without writing code to handle runtime permissions. On Android M, you can go to settings/app/yourapp/permissions. There i can see permission on phone, which upon inspecting, includes phone_state, which is a dangerous permission. Will my app automatically have the permission, if i give it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you give permission from settings your app will have those dangerous permissions.

You only need to request dangerous permissions at Runtime because by default you don't get those permissions with app installation.

> Let's understand it this way, if app is launched and tries to access
>   the dangerous functionality, it will crash as it won't get that
>   permission, so at that time you need to request those permissions
>   explicitly from users, **But if you manually give those dangerous
>   permissions from settings app than your app won't need to request
>   those permissions again explicitly at tuntime**

Answer (score 0):

Your app will gain the permissions you give it from the settings menu, but it's better practice if you show a permission dialog on first start and before starting activities which need those permissions. This is a sample of how to do that:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestAppPermissions(new
                String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i know how to write it in code, problem is managment doesn't want me to do so, and i had to a find a way for it to work on M.